# Why do the R and Python FFT give different results?

Tags: python, r, numpy, fft

I was running a simple experiment when I noticed a difference between R's and Python's FFT.

First, Python:

````
import numpy as np
from pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft import fft
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
fft(a)
>> array([ 6. +0.j       , -1.5+0.8660254j, -1.5-0.8660254j])

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
fft(b)
>> array([[ 6. +0.j       , -1.5+0.8660254j, -1.5-0.8660254j],
       [15. +0.j       , -1.5+0.8660254j, -1.5-0.8660254j]])```
````

Now R:

```
> a = c(1, 2, 3)
> fft(a)
[1]  6.0+0.000000i -1.5+0.866025i -1.5-0.866025i

> b = rbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
> fft(b)
      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 21+0i -3+1.732051i -3-1.732051i
[2,] -9+0i  0+0.000000i  0+0.000000i
```

I notice that the first row of the R result corresponds to the element-wise sum of the first and second row of the Python result, whereas the second row of the R result corresponds to the subtraction.

What am I doing wrong? I run the same experiment using np.matrix and R matrix, but got the same results. Which one should be the correct result when applying the FFT to a matrix or multidimensional array?

Comment: It looks like the Python FFT is 1D, and the R FFT is 2D. Try `fft2` in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `fftn` instead and it worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion in the comments, I did the following:

```
from pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft import fftn
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
fftn(b)                                                                                                                                                                                              
>> array([[21.+0.j        , -3.+1.73205081j, -3.-1.73205081j],
          [-9.+0.j        ,  0.+0.j        ,  0.+0.j        ]])
```

which works with `fft2` too.

Indeed, Python FFT is 1D (over each row) unless `fft2` or `fftn` are used.